# Why the rule against third party worlds?

Tags: discussion

There is a rule against asking questions about worlds and features from third party works, and I find this rule to be unhelpful for numerous reasons. While there is some explanation [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/policy-clarification-asking-about-commercial-or-third-party-worlds), there are still many problems:

1. The rule, in enforcement, actually just forbids people from giving context to their questions about third party worlds. It is impossible to have an encyclopedic knowledge of every feature in every world, or to even know which world, if any, an idea came from. Hence, apart from well-known features of well-known worlds, it is only possible to find out about such a question if the asker says outright that it is about a third party world
2. SciFi.SE, while it does allow questions to stray out of pure canon, is not WB.SE. It is based on the specific canon of a work, so I don't see them, for example, being able to tell the evolutionary history of a species seen only twice in a high-school dramedy that never once mentions evolution. Furthermore, SciFi.SE, from what I've read, is to assume normal science for the scientific questions, which is not useful if you're querying a world where you don't think normal science would fully apply in the area your question is about. For these reasons it is insufficient for querying new features for worlds
3. The justification that WB.SE isn't about how other worlds work doesn't hold up to scrutiny. No world is complete, and there are always more features you could add to someone's world. For example, let's you ask about the best way for the zekes from the Gone series could implement features from blue bats. The answers to this question would describe a unique idea, never seen in the series it is from. To declare this to be part of how that world works is like saying that building an extension is a contemplation of the house
4. The rule is inconsistent with the rest of the rules: I have asked several questions about building up on an existing world, as I assume many others have too. This was allowed because said existing world was yet to be put out into the world. I cannot see any way that a world would be so different before and after publishing as to warrant this rule

Taking these objections into account, why must we have this rule?

Comment: Your method of question-asking is better suited for Quora or Reddit. Both Stack Exchange and this Stack have rules, and one such rule is that questions are expected to be for the purpose of building a fictional world of your own creation. Non-Real-World questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds are better asked at [scifi.se] and Real World questions not asked for the purpose of building a fictional world of your own creation are  better asked at the appropriate Stack (e.g., [physics.se], [chemistry.se], [earthscience.se], [history.se], etc.)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this query. I don't read it as a duplicate: the other question is existential, should we have this policy or not along with supporting rationales. It's a fine question and, at least until the policy is properly challenged, I'd consider it a settled matter.  But here OP isn't asking whether or not a policy ought or noughtn't be made, but rather, seems more interested in (rather narrow) matters of application & applicability.

Comment: I understand the reason for closure, but I think, when viewed as a question of clarification, there are some concepts brought up that could be misunderstandings or misinterpretations  worthy of address.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact I do not know if you have read much fan fiction, but a great many of them vastly expand on existing worlds, and quite a few authors purposely diverge from canon where they have different needs. Writing a fanfic does not mean you are not building a world. In fact, many of my questions on this site have (secretly) been for a fan fiction, and nobody has ever questioned my intent with them.

Comment: I basically think that the only argument against answers including third-party worlds is the presumption that canonicity is an essential criterium for answer validity. If answerers are allowed to treat the question body as the full context, and "in canon reference works A and B it said..." is not automatically accepted (as it would be on SciFi.SE), then there's no reason to treat a Star Trek question any differently from one about the [C.A.S.T.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/why-does-the-conjoined-alliance-of-space-travellers-keep-producing-red-uniforms).

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Fanfiction is, at least in my opinion, a grey area, and one of the concepts that I think could be addressed. In short: I'd say that asking how Polyjuice Potion works in the wizarding world is off topic *here*; while asking how one might construct a plausible pseudolycanthropic potion for a fanfic would be on topic. Maybe splitting a hair, but in this example, you'd only be asking about "your portion" of the commercial world. And that's the reason no one has questioned your motive --- *you haven't been asking how the author's world works!*

Comment: @elemtilas But asking how the author's world works is not worldbuilding to begin with. That's like asking how Greek mythology works, which we don't do, whereas we do ask about creating our own version of a Zeus. Such answers may take inspiration from specific myths, but they are not bound to established lore, and briefly stating the canonical explanation for Zeus' power (assuming there is one) is not automatically the best or "correct" answer. I don't see the difference between mythology and third-party worlds: a worldbuilding question is a worldbuilding question.

Comment: But seeing as we frankly agree for the most part, I think I am going to propose a [tag:third-party-worlds] tag and have it put a warning above the question like the [tag:hard-science] one, reading something like: "This user is building their world based on a third-party world. The purpose of this question is to expand on the source material, not to expand one's understanding of it. Canonicity with all of the original lore is not a criterium for answer validity, only with what has been established in the question body."

Comment: @KeizerHarm Should perhaps write an answer summing up your point of view ;). I do find the tag idea appealing, though the question remains in how it will be put in practice by people.

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Unless I misunderstand you, I think we're in agreement. When it comes to third party worlds, we send people to SCI-FI/FANT, when it comes to mythology, we send people to Mythology & Folklore. As I replied to you before, you didn't get your questions closed because you *weren't* asking about the primary author's world or about the mythworld. Rather, you're presumably asking about the parts of the world that you're devising -- the canon extensions.

Comment: @elemtilas I think we are in *mostly* agreement :) My point is that "when it comes to third party worlds" is too broad a descriptor and rule. Had I mentioned "this is a <> fanfic" at the start of my questions but otherwise kept them the same, I am certain they would have been hit with down- and/or close-votes. The ban on naming the broader setting robs the question of some of their context, and the creative people on Wb.SE love context. Writing them has also sometimes been awkward; one time I have had to beg a frame challenger to just trust me that the issue they see isn't an issue.

Comment: That's what the proposed tag is for: to allow adding some more context to worldbuilding questions, as long as they are still doing actual worldbuilding.

Comment: I have submitted my proposal as an answer. I'm excited for the response!

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Wouldn't be downvoted by me! As for *naming the Nameless*, I honestly would not have a problem with that at all. Just make an unobtrusive statement like "I'm writing a fanfic based in Minchin's *Wherever Ever Land*." Folks can look it up if they want the context, but since your question focuses on your own fanfic, you don't really need to make any further mention.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Fan fiction belongs on [scifi.se].  This Stack's purpose is only to support people creating their own worlds. Why? (1) It guarantees no violation of copyright (if you want to argue with me about that, note that I ran a publishing house for 10 years that included a LOT of experience with copyright.) (2) Figuring out what rules of *someone else's world* can be bent, broken, modified, or deleted is not our mandate. (3) We are not *everything for everyone.* If Someone wants this Stack to be something other than what it is, they're welcome to join Quora or Reddit.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate to, "[Policy Clarification: Asking about commercial or third-party worlds](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7334/40609)." When it was re-opened, the link to that fact was deleted.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact "fan fiction belongs on science fiction & fantasy" - in what manner? There is a tag fan-fiction with 259 questions (out of 180 thousand) and they all seem to be story identification questions. How can fan fiction be said to belong there?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact You can also use your point 3 against every and all proposed rule changes, it is frankly not a very convincing argument to me.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Asking "does this change support or hinder the goals of the site?" is an important question to ask for any rules change. It should be asked before every proposed rule change. Pretty much by definition changes that support the goals of of the site should be enacted and those that hinder them should be rejected.

Comment: @KeizerHarm To give you a clearer picture of the goal of StackExchanges priorities [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) says *We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A; system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers**. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it.*

Comment: @sphennings Once again all that is completely obvious. Do you realise that I have the exact same interests at heart as you do? Do you think I don't want user happiness? The difference is that we disagree whether my proposal does more good or more harm. Stuff like "If you don't like the site go to Reddit" is such a non-argument.

Comment: @sphennings You would have to assume that I am some kind of misanthrope, in order to think that the the priority of maximising answerer happiness is new to me. I frankly feel offended by the suggestion. You can intellectually disagree with me, you can explain why my proposal sucks on every side, without questioning whether or not my intention is to improve the site.

Answer (score 4):

### Some Considerations

This is a question of application of the Policy on Commercial & Third-Party Fictional Worlds. The basic policy is **We have an unwritten rule that questions about commercial worlds (e.g. Star Wars, Star Trek, Babylon 5, etc.) should be asked on the Science Fiction & Fantasy stack**; and its [description and discussion can be read here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/policy-clarification-asking-about-commercial-or-third-party-worlds). I think it is fair to say that the general consensus of the community is that this is a settled matter. We have a gentlesophont's agreement with the good folks over at SF & F where we send them queries about Marvel Comix and Lord of the Rings, and they send us stray questions about fictional worlds that don't fall within their bailiwick.

That said, the following is my take on your question as it relates to the named policy.

---

> **I.** The rule, in enforcement, actually just forbids people from giving context to their questions about third party worlds. It is impossible to have an encyclopedic knowledge of every feature in every world, or to even know which world, if any, an idea came from. Hence, apart from well-known features of well-known worlds, it is only possible to find out about such a question if the asker says outright that it is about a third party world

I'd argue that the whole point of the rule is to prevent queries about third party worlds from being asked here in the first place. There is no good reason for anyone to have to "give context" about their third party world questions, because the proper forum for asking how such worlds behave is in fact SF&F. Questions about magic and technology and special powers of various races of people are commonplace there. For our part, we respect the boundary between "our own fictional worlds" and "JRR Tolkien's fictional world" by asking questions about the Silmarillion over there and our own fidgettywatties over here.

As for encyclopaedic knowledge, that's why we have SF&F! Their strong point is knowledge of the lore of any of hundreds of third party worlds. Some are very well known and part of common culture, others are so obscure that the only person who knows about them is the querent herself!

---

> **IJ.** SciFi.SE, while it does allow questions to stray out of pure canon, is not WB.SE. It is based on the specific canon of a work, so I don't see them, for example, being able to tell the evolutionary history of a species seen only twice in a high-school dramedy that never once mentions evolution. Furthermore, SciFi.SE, from what I've read, is to assume normal science for the scientific questions, which is not useful if you're querying a world where you don't think normal science would fully apply in the area your question is about. For these reasons it is insufficient for querying new features for worlds

SF&F can and does engage in thoughtful and considered speculation. If you can name the world that high school dramedy is set in and name the creature, I'd put a penny to a pound that someone over there can give you a reasonable speculation based on what is known of that world. And if no canon description is available, because the Author did not provide one, and the matter is beyond speculation, because the Author did not provide enough background, they will tell you flat out that the question is not answerable. And that's your answer!

I think your point *might possibly* stem from a misinterpretation of what the two forums exist for. SF&F exists to give strongly factual or at least solidly conjectural answers to questions about third party fictional worlds. It's not their job to engage in wild speculation or to create headcanon or even to answer questions about one's own fanfic.

On the other hand, WB exists for the express purpose of helping anyone devise, construct or discover *their own fictional world*. We can give strongly factual, solidly conjectural, flimsily conjectural or even bonkozoid crazy answers to any question the writer or worldbuilder or geopoet might have.

That said, it is also not our job to cater to idle curiosity about a third party world. Questions such as the example evolutionary consideration you mention are simply as off topic here as it is in SF&F. This is because, WB has to at least try to conform to Stack Exchange's forum model. These kinds of questions lend themselves to being too broad, too opinion based (even for me!) and also quite literally *can not be answered* because there is no canon data upon which to formulate an appropriate answer.

Hence, the rule about sticking to your own work here in WB. If you ask a question about the evolution of some creature seen in a high school dramedy that *you yourself wrote*, we'll be able to provide you top notch answers. And the reason is quite simply because you are the author and only you can really determine which answer fits your world's circumstances best.

---

> **IJI.** The justification that WB.SE isn't about how other worlds work doesn't hold up to scrutiny. No world is complete, and there are always more features you could add to someone's world. For example, let's you ask about the best way for the zekes from the Gone series could implement features from blue bats. The answers to this question would describe a unique idea, never seen in the series it is from. To declare this to be part of how that world works is like saying that building an extension is a contemplation of the house

I certainly concur: no fictional world is ever complete. (One could argue that the real world isn't even truly complete yet, let alone perfected.) And that is precisely why WB as a forum exists! To help folks on their path towards a world that is just a little less incomplete than it was before the question was asked.

However, you seem to be proceeding from a false presumption about this forum. Your presume that this forum, WB, exists to engage in idle speculation about somebody else's work. The Gone series of books was written by (I hazard the guess!) somebody other than you. The author's name is [Michael Grant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Grant_(author,_born_1954)). You can read the books, you can examine fan sites, you can immerse yourself in lore related forums, you can look at the linked webpage, you can consider all the influences on his writing and you can privately speculate all you want on the conjunction of zekes and blue bats.

Interesting as that speculation assuredly is, it is off topic here in WB. If anyone were to post that question in WB, it would be closed for being off topic. They'd be invited to read the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help), refresh their memory by [taking the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), and perhaps even review [what this forum is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).

Such speculations and idle dreamthoughts do indeed have their place in worldbuilding! In the article on [Worldbuilding Resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) there is, under the heading **Worldbuilding Discussion Forums**, a number of highly interesting long & short form discussion groups where this kind of cross-over speculation can be engaged in.

---

> **IJJI.** The rule is inconsistent with the rest of the rules: I have asked several questions about building up on an existing world, as I assume many others have too. This was allowed because said existing world was yet to be put out into the world. I cannot see any way that a world would be so different before and after publishing as to warrant this rule

Possibly the seeming inconsistency of the Policy evolves from a really bad misunderstanding or misinterpretation of 1) the Policy itself, 2) the nature of the forum it applies to and 3) the nature of the question's matter itself.

I know you have indeed asked many questions in WB! I've answered some of them! (And I hope I gave some help or inspiration to you, if not the very best answer you were looking for.) You've asked questions that we presume are about your own worldbuilding; and you've also asked questions about other people's worldbuilding. E.g., the example question about Michael Grant's zekes.

1 . The policy itself exists in order to separate and corral queries based on the forum's competency to answer. Math questions go to Mathematics, WWII questions go to History. In our case, *Gone* questions go to SF&F, while World of Ichthys King questions remain here in WB. Simply put, there's a division of labour in Stack Exchange, and to our lot falls queries about your own worldbuilding.

2a. The natures of the two forums in question are important to understand. SF&F clearly delineates what they are about:

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> Plot, character, or setting explanations
> Historical or societal context of a work
> Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> Story identification
> Franchise/series reading or viewing order

2b. They are also clear as to what they are *nòt about*:

> If your question is about...
>
> Writing science fiction or fantasy, ask on Writers Stack Exchange.
> Creating a fictional situation or universe of your own or investigating the plausibility of an element of another work of fiction, ask on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

3 . And before you cry aha! WB is about "investigating the plausibility of an element of another work of fiction!", this brings us to the nature of the question's material itself. Do keep in mind that that wording is taken from SF&F's help center, not WB's. [Our own verbiage](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is much more creator-centric. For example, ***the goal of the site is to help you build your world***. If it is your desire to understand the "plausibility of an element" within your own worldbuilding, we expect you to ask your question having already resolved the hows and whys of that element in its own context. This is because that material is not yours! It belongs to another geopoet, and we are not competent to answer on their behalf! Our job is to help you take your understanding of that element in the other Author's work and apply it to your own world. In order to do that, you would need to study that element and its context elsewhere. When you ask your question, you would need to post appropriate links to that external information, and then ask your own query about your own world. The situation is comparable to "real world questions". Generally speaking, they are welcome here, but with caveats. The querent needs to have already done some homework on the real world issue and they need to give appropriate background and context of their own world.

---

**Summation:**

> I cannot see any way that a world would be so different before and after publishing as to warrant this rule

At last we get to the crux of the original question! The simple fact of the matter is that this Policy and its application quite literally ***have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the world itself!!*** You're quite correct in saying that there is no difference in a world --- qua mundo ipso --- before and after publication.

The underlying issue is that the Policy pertains to *the geopoet herself as author & creator of the fictional world* and not the world she has wrought.

For example, let's go back to the zekes. *Gone* is off topic here not because the world the stories are set in seems no different before and after publication, but simply because you, Ichthys King, are not that world's creator and are not that story's author. Nor am I. Nobody else in WB is either. The geopoet's name is Michael Grant. Michael Grant the geopoet, and by extension his corpus of work, is the only competent resource we have for settling questions about mutated wormlike creatures called zekes. Since Michael is not here in WB (that we know of!) to ask us questions about how zekes work, and since you are not the worldbuilder who has made the world the zekes inhabit, such questions are off topic here.

In a nutshell, the rule is warranted here because you're asking us to answer questions that you should be addressing to Michael Grant himself! The rule is warranted here because you're not asking us to help you understand or solve a problem with your own worldbuilding.

I guess that's two nutshells!  I guess consider it a walnut and I really do hope that I've answered your concerns about the Policy in a sensible manner. I'm happy to clarify anything further and edit any factual errors as needed.

---

### Follow-up Points

> Your point about only asking on your own world isn't sensible. For example, let's say that while you are on a walk, you meet someone who decided (for some reason) to tell you about a magic creature she designed. She then goes on to say that her friend went to WB.SE to ask about if it could exist realistically. Would this scenario make you justified in seeking said question out and closing it for being off topic?
>
> Furthermore, not all queries about third party worlds are specifically about canon, and can't all be best answered by the author. As an example, I doubt that Swift could give you a scientific explanation of the liliputians, even ignoring that he died in the 18th century –
>
> Finally, framing third party questions as 'idle curiosity' is not an argument. I could just as easily say that asking about your own world is 'idle curiosity', and be just as wrong and hollow as you

This is a classic scenario that actually makes the argument in favour of the Policy in question, as well as in favour of other rules and customs of SE and WB specifically.

1. The claim that the rule is not sensible is a valid opinion. Rather than argue opinion vs opinion, if I were in that situation I'd simply recommend that the person join this great worldbuilding Q&A forum *herself*! End of story. I know that some people in this community would seek out and VTC the friend's question. I would not *necessárily* do that, as it would depend on how the question is worded. We rely on querents being honest in representing themselves as engaging in their own worldbuilding. If someone straight up said that they're asking on behalf of a friend, the community would be 100% justified in closing the question and inviting the person's friend to join so she can ask her own questions and evaluate the answers she receives based on her own worldbuilding work. This is a very simple and non-controversial policy.
2. Ultimately, all questions about third party fictional worlds boil down to canon. You bring up Liliputians: whether or not Swift could address a "scientific explanation" for that race or not, the fact remains that he is the only one who is truly competent to unequivocally evaluate an answer that explains them because, again, he is the geopoet that created the world the Liliputians inhabit.
3. It's never been proposed that all third-party world related queries are questions of idle curiosity. That's something you should address in another question. Suffice to say it is the custom of WB.SE to deny idle questions simply because they stray from the whole point of this forum and the askers of such questions are demanding an improper waste the time and effort of those of us who actually answer questions. If you want to ask an idle question about Liliputians, or anything else, I charge $75/hr for internet based research and $150/hr for book based research. If you're going to waste time on idle curiosity, you're at least going to make it worth my while to do your homework for you. Lastly, it is ever the case that those without good arguments always resort to ad hominem attacks or personal insult.

> *What do you reckon opinion based questions have to do with third party questions?*
>
> It's simple logic: If a question involving some canon is best answered by that canon, then it follows that a question involving opinion (i.e. all of them) is best answered by opinions, and so must be opinion based –
>
> On the point of it being like the real world: I agree. So why must we bar questions that take elements from a third party world to make something new, when we allow questions that take elements from reality to make something new?

1 . That doesn't logically follow. "Canon" means the established facts of a fictional world or setting. Opinions aren't established facts of anything. Opinion based questions, at their worst, are simply a querent dredging the community for *opinions* -- what colour should it be -- what do you think this would look like -- which feature should I choose. They can be improved by the addition of context, focus and criteria.

2 . I think you're missing the point of the issue. On real world queries, facts are universal in nature and knowledge of them can be acquired from one's own experience, research and the expertise of others. No one here on Earth owns *reality*, so no person here on Earth is the competent authority to ask questions of. Answers can be judged, by the OP and by the Community, based on the corpus of human knowledge and wisdom.

On our own fictional worlds, the OP is not only the creator of the setting, but is also the keeper of all knowledge about the fictional world. The OP is the competent judge of all responses to her queries.

When it comes to third party worlds, I believe your initial assumption is incorrect. In this case, the creator of the setting and the competent judge of all queries is not the same person as the querent. We **do not accept** such question here because the querent can not judge the validity of the answers. Also, our express purpose in this forum is to help the querent build *their own* fictional worlds, not help them understand how *somebody else's* world works.

In the specific application of somebody else's work, a third party world, to the querent's own work, you have a valid point and my take is that there is no problem at all with asking a question of application of a third party world's elements to your own. However, there is an important caveat to understand. This is the underlying point of your original question; and I think it is also the stumbling block that you've set up for yourself in understanding how this forum works vs how other open ended forums work. Namely, Worldbuilding.SE is not the forum to ask this kind of research question in. As it happens, there is a very simple progression you can follow. The logical steps are:

**First**,  do your own research. Like if you want to meld Ents and mermaids into one kind of creature, you would do your own basic research on those two topics.

**Second**, you would address any canonical queries re Ents in SF&F. That forum is where you could address questions of anatomy, physiology & evolution of Ents with respect to the lore of Tolkien's legendarium -- the canon.

**Third**, once you've got some understanding of you're working with, you are certainly free to ask queries of application queries here. For example, knowing that the Entwives have disappeared, and knowing that Ents are a kind of plantimal being and guardian force protective of the natural world, you might consider that the Entwives were driven from their terrestrial haunts and sought refuge in the sea. You could then ask about adaptation of your own Ent-like plantimal creature to a maritime environment, given X, Y & Z conditions of the world they inhabit and considering P, R & S  constraints.

Following these steps will turn low quality brainstorming and opinion type questions into awesome queries of deep geopoesy, questions that will challenge the respondent and make the whole process satisfying and unfrustrating, questions that will set WB.SE apart from the open ended worldbuilding ruminations one finds on Reddit.

> If it is solely based on who made the world/feature, then why are questions about dragons, mermaids, and unicorns so accepted as to have their own tags? No-one here made any of those creatures, yet everyone and anyone is free to ask questions about these and make judgements on the answers.

Yay! Progress! Precisely! This is because "dragons" and "mermaids" are not the distinct creation of any one individual. They are creations of human culture and are thus the common property of all humanity. It is precisely because no one made or owns those ideas that we can use them freely in our own worlds, modify them and ask questions about them here.

> Why does the same not apply to more recently made worlds? Any justification I can think of for the former applies equally to the latter –

Now, Tolkien made use of this situation and created at least two named dragons, the more famous I'm sure being Smaug. So, asking if Smaug actually had a chink in his armour where he could be shot by this huge six foot long rod of iron as we see in the movie, that is a question for SF&F because Smaug belongs to JRRT and is governed by the canon of his legendarium. Asking about dragons in general, whether they have "armoured scales" and whether shooting them with long iron spikes might be a good way to slay them, that is an acceptable question for WB. This is because the querent is taking the same stock of raw materials that Tolkien took from and is creating her own legendarium, her own world.

Very simply, we don't answer questions about someone else's canon here. End of story. That is one reason why SF&F exists. Sorry, but all the justifications you might make simply run afoul of how Stack Exchange works.

Your line of argumentation is like the man set up a tiny house on the handicapped parking spots at Walmart, and, when questioned by the police gave the answer: but officer, everyone has the right to live in their own house, and this is my house. That line of argumentation misses the point entirely, because it ignores the fundamental point that the house is sitting on the handicapped parking spaces!

> KeizerHarm: While I frankly agree with 95% of the things you have said here, I do agree with Ichtys that "only the author of a world can judge the best thing for a world" is a strange axiom, and I do not understand if it is rooted in your ethical values or in practical considerations. It is hard to hold when it comes to public domain works. You say that only Swift can judge competently what to do with Liliputians, does that mean that every movie adaptation of Sherlock Holmes is by definition incompetent, since they weren't made by Arthur Conan Doyle? Can Guy Ritchie visit this site?

That axiom is simply the logical distillation of how WB works. When you ask a question about a problem you're having with your own worldbuilding, I can write an answer in an effort to be helpful. I can perhaps try to inspire, to offer some levity or some creativity, but one thing I can not do is *make the decision for you*. No one else here can make the decision for you. When I try to do that, someone will (rightly) accuse me building your world for you. Note that the result of you judging the "best answer" for your world is that coveted green checkmark! Stack Exachange itself actually builds into the functionality of our forum the principle that only the querent can choose the "best answer", and this is done separately from the community voting on their favourite answer.

So, if only KeizerHarm can judge answers given for the world KeiserHarm made, and only Ichthys King can judge answers given for the world Ichthys King made, why should it be any different for questions & answers about the world that JRRT tolkien made, or the world JK Rowling made?

I agree with you on this: those worlds are, in a sense -- a cultural and non-legal sense -- part of the public domain. People dress up like Hogwarts students, they dress up like Hobbits and Elves, they dress up like Dr. Who characters of Marvel characters. They collect and make objects that come from those worlds. You can buy Harry Potter's official wand or Aragorn's official sword. Craftsmen and talented people make decorative and useful objects relating to those properties and people write stories and create games based on these popular worlds. To be frank, the only reason we don't take questions about those worlds is because SF&F exists as a forum! Can you imagine if we had to field all the questions about Harry Potter and Captain America and Tom Bombadil and Alice for people wanting to write fan fiction in those worlds if SF&F didn't exist!?

When I say "only Swift" can judge or "only Tolkien can judge", I rather thought it would be obvious that neither of those gentlemen would be actively and personally participating in these forums. We must therefore rely on -- canon. In Swift's case, that would involve the text of any of his works where Liliputians are mentioned (primary canon) and any of his papers or correspondence that talks about Liliputians (secondary canon). Tolkien is a much better example, because probably about 80 or 90 per cent of the secondary canon has now been published and probably 100% of his primary canon has been published. If you question about Tom Bombadil, you can read the narratives (Hobbit and LotR), and you can "ask Professor Tolkien" by the simple expedient of perusing CJRT's mammoth History of Middle Earth series, reading mentions made in his letters and checking into other major and minor works, like Silmarillion or the recently published Nature of Middle Earth.

As for legal derivative works (tertiary canon) -- essentially "officially sanctioned fan fiction" like Peter Jackson's movie adaptations, *The Cursed Child* and games like *Hogwarts Mystery* -- again, those are "worlds" created by an individual other than a person asking a question here in WB. This is why they're called "third party worlds". If Peter Jackson himself wanted to ask questions about Smaug here in WB, we would have closed his question for being off topic and would have sent him over to SF&F. Questions we have about those movies and other licensed properties are addressed in the appropriate forum.

Finally, as for legally grey derivative works (quaternary canon) -- essentially the fanfic I like to write about the wizarding world, or any of the Middle Earth derived worlds and cultures I've seen, and even including substantial works like *The Last Ringbearer* and *Хранители / Khraniteli* -- if you had a question about those, you'd also have to ask in SF&F because you're not asking a question about your own worldbuilding, but are asking about someone else's worldbuilding.

Lastly, if it's you doing the fanfic writing, and you have a question about some problem you're facing, I'd refer you to the Three Simple Steps process I laid out earlier for Ichthys King, as I think that would keep both forums neat, tidy and appropriately walled off from one another!

Comment: Your point about only asking on your own world isn't sensible. For example, let's say that while you are on a walk, you meet someone who decided (for some reason) to tell you about a magic creature she designed. She then goes on to say that her friend went to WB.SE to ask about if it could exist realistically. Would this scenario make you justified in seeking said question out and closing it for being off topic?

Comment: Furthermore, not all queries about third party worlds are specifically about canon, and can't all be best answered by the author. As an example, I doubt that Swift could give you a scientific explanation of the liliputians, even ignoring that he died in the 18th century

Comment: Finally, framing third party questions as 'idle curiosity' is not an argument. I could just as easily say that asking about your own world is 'idle curiosity', and be just as wrong and hollow as you

Comment: @IchthysKing --  I address your arguments in the body of the response.

Comment: Your follow-up to my second point is nonsensical. Claiming that every question involving third-party worlds is based on the world's canon is as ridiculous as claiming that every question about how something looks is based on how cool it looks. If I ask for a sensible reason why someone would set themselves on fire, would 'keeping cool' be a valid answer by virtue of it coming from me, who asked the question?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- You're comparison is faulty.  Even if you're asking a speculative question, like the evolution of Liliputians, that speculation is still based on the canon established by Swift. Your example is also faulty.  If you asked why someone would set themselves on fire, I'd recommend you go ask that person! Anyway, that is clearly not a worldbuilding question so much as a storybuilding question and would be closed for being off topic.

Comment: Yes, canon would be important to the question, just as aesthetics will probably feature into many questions regarding appearance. This does not mean that the answers must be based on canon. If you disagree, then come back in 3 years once you've cleared up all the opinion-based questions

Comment: @IchthysKing -- As I see it, asking about someone else's world is kind of like asking a real world question. You don't really get a whole lot of wiggle room with either kind of question. So yeah, asking about someone else's world is really very canon dependent. This problem resolves itself when we do our own worldbuilding here in stead of second guessing someone else's.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- What do you reckon opinion based questions have to do with third party questions?

Comment: It's simple logic: If a question involving some canon is best answered by that canon, then it follows that a question involving opinion (i.e. all of them) is best answered by opinions, and so must be opinion based

Comment: On the point of it being like the real world: I agree. So why must we bar questions that take elements from a third party world to make something new, when we allow questions that  take elements from reality to make something new?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Addressed in response.

Comment: 1. If deep research was a hard requirement for questions, then I (and many others) would not have a single upvote (or even a question or answer). And if this requirement is just for third-party worlds, then we still need justification for this disjoint standard

Comment: 2. What exactly is the difference between another person's world and your own world heavily inspired by another person's world? Unless there is some sort of hive mind I don't know about, then the way ideas work means that there is no difference, as any world in your mind will be altered by the uniqueness of your brain. Hence, if any world you ask about is inherently your own, then why should the rules be different for some of these worlds?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- I didn't say "deep" research, but rather "basic" research. Research is an expectation for asking **any question** here in WB.SE. You don't need a PhD to ask, but you should have some basic understanding. Lack of basic research is often the cause of downvotes. So yeah, you might want to reconsider your research vs fishing expedition vs  question asking strategy!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 2. Serious question: do you understand the concept of different human beings being discrete individuals each being capable of & responsible for their own cognitive activities? I don't want to insult you or anything, your line of reasoning seems to be a little off on this matter. Just to clarify: here in WB, you ask about your own world; over on SF&F, you ask about other people's worlds. You =/= other people. You did not create their world. You have no authority over it. You can not judge the validity of answers over someone else's work. Don't go there. Just accept that...

Comment: @IchthysKing -- ... there is a division between two forums where questions about your own work are acceptable (WB) and where questions about someone else's work are acceptable (SF&F). You don't need to propose hive minds or anything crazy. It's a very simple arrangement and it works. Get with the programme or else you're going to keep suffering closure after closure and probably will be expelled from the forum for arrogant disregard of house rules.

Comment: On 2: If it is soley based on who made the world/feature, then why are questions about dragons, mermaids, and unicorns so accepted as to have their own tags? No-one here made any of those creatures, yet everyone and anyone is free to ask questions about these and make judgements on the answers. Why does the same not apply to more recently made worlds? Any justification I can think of for the former applies equally to the latter

Comment: @elemtilas while I frankly agree with 95% of the things you have said here, I do agree with Ichtys that "only the author of a world can judge the best thing for a world" is a strange axiom, and I do not understand if it is rooted in your ethical values or in practical considerations. It is hard to hold when it comes to public domain works. You say that only Swift can judge competently what to do with Liliputians, does that mean that every movie adaptation of Sherlock Holmes is by definition incompetent, since they weren't made by Arthur Conan Doyle? Can Guy Ritchie visit this site?

Comment: How many authors must be involved in making a world before it can be asked about here? And why that value?

Comment: Why do more authors allow us to speculate more?

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Answered in response.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 1. So long as it's ***not your world*** you're asking about, you ask elsewhere. When it is ***your world*** you're asking about, ask here! In all honesty, the number of authors may be infinite! Sooner or later, works by known authors become part of folklore and mythology. When that happens, we send your questions over to Mythology and Folklore!  2. We can speculate all we want. No author can stop fans from doing that.

Comment: @elemtilas 1. How do you know whether I'm asking about my world or someone else's? 2. So why can't we use this forum to aid our speculation?

Comment: @IchthysKing I think there's a reasonable barrier between speculation about author's intent with a world (literary analysis) and speculation about the implications of something existing (general sciencey analysis).

Comment: @elemtilas I think we end up disagreeing only on one comparatively point: when exactly someone else's world becomes my world. Ent-wives as your example: once an author interprets them (maybe using SciFi.SE) and established their own rules for the species, then they are welcome on Worldbuilding with their version of the species, that they have to exhaustively describe in order to get complete answers, correct? So a question: "My lightsabers work like in Star Wars but they burn at 3000 Celcius and can do X Y - can they do Z?" is fine? If yes, then...

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 1. We assume you are an honourable and decent person with no malice at heart or foul intentions in mind. If you have been misrepresenting yourself and your intent when asking your questions, then there are only two valid options. You either need to remove yourself from this forum or else be expelled. 2. Asked and answered. NUMEROUS TIMES! As I've said already maybe 23 times, feel free to ask questions and perhaps even speculate all you want. Just don't be a jerk about it!

Comment: ...then the only thing we two disagree about is that I do that layer of interpretation implicitly. I would never ask about the Lightsaber as it exists in George Lucas' mind because I have nothing to do with that. That's not what I do with fanfics either. My mind is a layer of interpretation, and I would only ask about things that I have straightened out into systems myself. For example putting a level of Newtons on Avatar's waterbending. At that point, the only reason I would name the setting is to give inspiration to answerers. That's what my proposal was most about.

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Quite possibly! And I think this touches upon the question you asked in Meta. You kind of know my thoughts on that somewhat already. The short answer is that worlds like Middle Earth and the Wizarding World will **never** be mine. When I write fan fiction it is with the full knowledge that I am playing in JKR's sandbox and that I can never exercise complete control over my work, because it is derivative, and quite possibly I may never be able to seek recompense for that work. That said, ...

Comment: @elemtilas 1. I don't see how having an incorrect assumption made about your question is some great sin to be purged. And the point of that question was that if you can't reliably tell someone's own world from another person's, then you can't have a rule that delineates between the two 2. I don't understand this point. What has "being a jerk" got to do with anything?

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- (cont) ... there are certainly *aspects* or portions of the Wizarding World that are mine. Characters, storylines, some places, some spells and potions. None of those are  of sufficient canonicity that anyone will ever be worried enough to be asking questions about them. But even so, I would understand my question asking limits thus: if I had a question about a location for a plot or a likely outcome of a botched potion, I wouldn't ask those questions here. Without question,

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- (cont) ... those are queries for SF&F because they relate to WW canon, even though that question pertains to my little bit of the wizarding world. If I ask a question about my own worldbuilding, I'd certainly ask here in WB! And I think I have actually asked two questions here!  And in so far as your fanfic query about water speed attainable by an Avatar waterbending, I think when you have the canon well understood, and are really only mentioning the source to, as you say, give inspiration, then I'd say you should be fine here in WB. At that point, the query isn't about canon.

Comment: I have not seen a question on SF&F where the author states the purpose of their question as a fanfic, but the clearest version of that mentioned barrier between the two is that SF&F is still literary interpretation. WB cannot contain literary interpretation, so it needs complete systems as input, not links to works. Then the edge case: a system prominent in a work but softly defined, and I refined it to specificity to use for my work. Then asking about that system as refined... I suppose a reason against name-dropping it is that I may be confusing readers into doing literary interpretation?

Comment: @elemtilas Another point: SF&F is, from what I know, supposed to answer based on canon. Based on your idea about division of labour on Stack Exchange, then heavy speculation about third-party worlds, such as parsing out how evolution would work in the world of Fruits Basket, would fall in our field

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 1. If you're not able to distinguish your own work from that of Tolkien, then I really can't help you any more! I think I've been more than clear already! 2. You intimated that you might have ulterior motives in asking your questions here. Remember? You said *How do you know whether I'm asking about my world or someone else's?* If you've been asking about someone else's world all this time, then yeah, you're being a jerk. A dishonest scoundrel. You'd be wasting my time and efforts. Being a jerk has to do with whether you actually belong here  or whether you should be booted.

Comment: @IchthysKing Still ultimately subject to author's intent, as I understand it. WB is not about authors, and the evolution of Liliputians is ultimately whatever the author wants it to be. I think I agree with elementilas now that such questions don't really belong here.

Comment: @elemtilas A common understanding on the site is that name-dropping works is itself a rule break, no matter whether the question is focused on them. I am now contemplating a new proposal zoning in on that specific bit: stating that name-dropping licensed works must be okay as long as the purpose of the name-drop is providing inspiration, and that the subject matter of the question must be an exhaustively described interpretation at the very least. Still brings up the kitchen sink argument of JBH's though.

Comment: What can I say, this stuff is complicated! Thank you for your thoughts and engagement.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Re SF&F, yep! You got it! I think we're approaching an understanding! And no, "heavy speculation about third-party world" would ***mostly certainly not*** fall in our field. Those kinds of open ended questions of speculation, conjecture and opionising belong somewhere else. I gave you a link to resources of other (excellent) worldbuilding forums where that kind of question is not only tolerated, but welcomed!

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- If name dropping is such an issue, then I think that is where your (original) tag proposal would work well.  And where I think your planned revision might work even better! And yes, either way, you (and the rest of us) would have to figure out the whole kitchen sink thing. ;)

Comment: @elemtilas It seems like you're focusing in too much on specific words that were poorly chosen. *I'm* not pretending that third-party questions are about my own world, but how do you know if *someone* is? Heavy *speculation* is off-topic, but that doesn't mean the *entire idea* of third-party questions is

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Okay. You're not pretending that third-party worlds are your own. I don't think I accused you of that! But if I did, then I apologise. As for how do we know when someone is asking about a third-party world? Well, fortunately, the old adage about the intelligence of criminals pertains: very often *they come right out and tell us* that they're asking about a third-party world! [This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52465/reality-check-batman) for example comes right out and asks what kind of guy Batman is.

Comment: @elemtilas *"They come right out and tell us"* And if they don't?

Comment: @IchthysKing Are you asking what should be done if people on WB claim to own third-party worlds? If someone came in and said they were JK Rowling?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- *Heavy speculation* is off topic because it invites opinion, and as you know that's off topic here. Also, speculative questions tend to be unfocused, rambling and lacking clarity. All of those are off topic. Per Stack Exchange! As JBH has eloquently explained before (and I'm certain it was him that did!) questions of speculation don't turn into a single best / most correct answer. If the querent gives no criteria for asking, then the querent can't judge the answer. And like I've said numerous times, if you can't judge the question well, it has problems and may be off topic.

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- As an aside, if JK Rowling came in here, and it turned out to actually be her, I'd certainly have a couple complaints about the most recent "books" that have been published!! But seriously, if she herself came here asking for help with worldbuilding, then we'd do what we always do: we'd welcome her, point her to the tour and help and remind her what WB is all about and we'd answer her worldbuilding queries to our accustomed high standard of quality.  And since it is JKR, we do not need to refer her to SF&F, because the WW is already her fictional world!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- "And if they don't?"  Well, what am I a mind reader? We just assume that they are honourable people with good intentions and no malice or sneakiness. Didn't I just something like that?

Comment: @elemtilas OK, speculation is off-topic. So what about if we had a solid, well-defined question about evolution in the world of Fruits Basket? That would easily fall within our worldbuilding scope. And on the next point: Wouldn't it be more fruitful to assume honesty if we weren't closing/downvoting people's questions due to said honesty? Because that's essentially what you're doing when you close a question for something you said can only be found by admission

Comment: @IchthysKing -- If the World of Fruit Baskets belongs to Ichthys King, then you are free to ask on-topic questions about it! If it's not your world, then no, you don't ask about it here, because it's someone else's world and falls under the third-party world policy. The only times I've ever seen third-party questions being closed are when either a) the querent straight up asks a question like "Where was Batman born?" or b) is asking about a setting that is very obviously not theirs. E.g. "I've got this castle in Scotland, it looks like ruins, but powerful magic actually keeps muggles away..."

Comment: @elemtilas Actually I personally *would* allow "I've got this castle in Scotland" questions. That author is, perhaps unwittingly, creating a layer of interpretation atop the published work and it (in my view) revolves back to him asking about his own world. Though then honest answerers should only use his description and not assume anything outside the description.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- If you ask questions about the World of Fruit Baskets, and it's not yours, and no one else has ever heard of it (maybe someone published some stories in a small fantasy zine back in the 80s) and you don't mention that it's not yours, we're just going to assume that you're being honest. If someone comes in a month or a decade later and discovers your treachery, then I think the community would be within rights to close the question. Other actionable possibilities may be taken up by SE, the original author, the owners or successors of the fantsy zine, etc.

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Slippery Slytherin!  I'd personally ask for clarification in comments. The closer the query mimics Hogwarts, and the more reticent the querent is to either admit a) yeah, I'm writing a HP fanfic or b) what is this Harry Potter thing you people keep badgering me about? then the more I'd become suspicious that the querent is trying to pull a fast one. Evidence or no, it would most likely be closed for being off topic. Perhaps story based! And then you could try to reopen it!

Comment: @elemtilas Though that's the thing. Take something about Wizarding World that hasn't been established, say internal temperature management of Hogwarts. There's two approaches. Go to SF&F and theorise using every bit of canon available. Or go to WB, with your own map of the castle in far greater detail than any canon; so much that the name and world barely matter any more, and ask about temperature management then. In my view, both questions would be fine. Because in the second one you're not asking anyone to do literary analysis; you are asking questions about your description of the castle.

Comment: And for the moment assuming that you also exhaustively described *your own analysis of* Wizarding World's soft magic system as it relates to indoors temperature management. At that moment, the only reason to still call it Hogwarts is to inspire answerers; it is not strictly necessary for a good answer.

Comment: @elemtilas *"If it's not your world, then no, you don't ask about it here, because it's someone else's world and falls under the third-party world policy"* Then where do we ask it? If it's a Stack-Exchange-Worthy question, then it should fit in somewhere; it doesn't make sense for some questions to be stuck in some limbo. The only options are: It belongs on SF&F, which doesn't make sense under your ideas of a division of labour (because they specialize in what already exists in the work); We need a new stack for building on existing worlds, which seems excessive; or Those questions belong here

Comment: @IchthysKing Honestly, I would help found a new one with you :) Though maybe SE's question-and-answer system doesn't work so well for literary analysis and heavy speculation atop it.

Comment: @IchthysKing There are plenty of questions that cannot be asked on any site on the stack exchange network. You're welcome to ask them elsewhere but if they're not a good fit for a site there is no obligation for SE to create a place for them.

Comment: @elemtilas Frankly the "Look at my map of Hogwarts-ish - what would it act like?" question would be a lot like the "Here's my specifications for a Batman-ish - could it work?" question. Asking about a provided interpretation instead of asking about an existing world.

Comment: @sphennings Do you have any examples of such questions?

Comment: @sphennings And isn't it a bad thing if some good questions are lost because of not having a place? Why should we shrink our reach and make that problem worse?

Comment: @IchthysKing Not really. The entire platform was build upon the idea that we should optimize for [good answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) not make sure every question is answered. It's very easy to spam low quality questions. If we wanted to serve every question then we wouldn't have a review queue. If you want a site where you can post whatever you want then this isn't the place for you. It's built into our DNA to have barriers and limits to filter out the low quality noise.

Comment: @sphennings So it's a bad thing if some good answers are lost because the questions they'd answer not having a place? Why should we shrink our reach and make that problem worse?

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- While I personally agree with you, a question about Hogwarts's that hasn't ever been established in any level of canon might seem to fit here, and I personally might choose not to close it if asked here, I'd still argue that others would be within rights to close it for any number of reasons. First & foremost, environmental control at Hogwarts is actually addressed in canon -- the House Elves stock all the hearths with wood and make sure the fires are kept alight -- but I'm certain that it would be closed for being opinion based. Because all (or most) answers are equally ...

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- ... valid, the querent can't make the determination which answer is the "best answer" per general SE rules. I think that in order to get around this problem, you'd have to have proposed that fanfic queries are okay given that done all the research, and are clear that the question is not one of canon but pertains strictly to your own work of fiction, etc!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- *Then where do we ask it?* Did you not read my response to your original question? Did you not read my recent comment? I gave you a link to worldbuilding resources that list a number of other excellent worldbuilding forums where those kinds of queries are not only tolerated but welcomed!

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Concur (mostly!) with asking about "interpretation" vs canon. But I still think not quite far enough. As I've said, I might be willing to let that question slide, but would not seek to reopen if it got closed for being about a third party world. Or for being opinion based or story based or something else. Speculative questions like that are regularly discussed on Reddit, and that's probably where I'd recommend the question be asked, especially when it's not crystal clear that the majority of the question is about your own work. We're getting down to the hair splitting now!

Comment: @elemtilas It is an honest edge case. If I am that far into mapping the castle I might as well call it Frogspots, ditch the canon characters, and I'll have an original world that happens to be inspired by Harry Potter! I'll ask on WB about Frogspots using my map and will be perfectly capable of choosing the best answer. So then the only difference between Frogspots (fine) and Hogwarts (bad) is my intent, which doesn't even need to be visible because the canon characters are unrelated to the matter of castle heating. And there's precedent: 50 Shades of Grey started out as Twilight fanfic

Comment: @elemtilas And none of said forums can be on SE, and so will not have the benefits and features of these sites

Comment: @IchthysKing We're here to make it easy to write good answers. Just because it's possible for someone to write a good answer from a poorly asked question doesn't mean it's easy to do so. Rejecting bad questions is built into the architecture of the site. Plenty of QA sites don't have the ability to close questions. If you don't like the structure that this site has you can ask your questions elsewhere.

Comment: @elemtilas Definitely agree that this is now close to hair splitting. I'm glad we've reached this level of agreement. I'll pause for the moment and ruminate - and maybe come with a new proposal if I find a place and wording for one.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 1. Take a look at the long list of closed questions in any SE forum. You're bound to find hundreds and thousands of questions that don't fit. 2. Two things you can do about questions that don't fit here in WB: first, take a look at Area-51 and make a proposal for a new SE forum, one that caters specifically to these lost questions; second, join us over on Codidact! I'm hoping that the worldbuilding & storywriting forum there will be able to handle a slightly less restricted array of question ...

Comment: @IchthysKing If you want the benefits of the structured Question and Answer format you need to follow the rules of that format.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- ... types. Bear in mind, I'm also hoping that the Codidact forum will reject idle curiosity questions and bump the quality of people's question up considerably. Not just "what would happen if a mermaid and ecnabian bat were crossed" but things like "assuming the cross happened, how might this that and the other physiological & cultural sequellae lead to the formation of such-and-such worldview and how might I apply that in my story".

Comment: @sphennings Why must questions about third party worlds be poorly asked and against SE's format?

Comment: @KeizerHarm -- Re Frogspots / 50 Shades: spot effing on! Since you're comparing it to 50 Shades, can we assume that Frogspots will involve a slightly saucier sort of activity? A magical map of that castle could reveal some interesting activities indeed!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- You're missing the point again. It doesn't matter if the third party world question is poorly worded or excellent in every regard. They're both off topic and for the same reason.

Comment: @elemtilas Aren't the different stacks for division of labour? Why should we have a new stack that's just worldbuilding but with the worlds coming from another source?

Comment: @elemtilas On your latest point: Are you saying that these questions, regardless of their quality, are off-topic because of being poor quality?

Comment: @IchthysKing Perhaps you should reread [this post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/policy-clarification-asking-about-commercial-or-third-party-worlds) on why we consider questions about existing works of fiction a poor fit for this site.

Comment: @sphennings I've already read that post thoroughly, which is why I asked this question in the first place

Comment: @IchthysKing -- The only pertinent division of labour is between WB and SF&F. You can answer your own question better than I can! -- You complained that some questions were becoming lost. Like I said, you have options, and one valid option is for you to propose a new group at Area 51. I think your better option is Codidact, personally, but it's your choice.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- "You're missing the point again. It doesn't matter if the third party world question is poorly worded or excellent in every regard. They're both off topic and for the same reason." It's the same reason we've been talking about all day and for a long while before. Read back through the comments or reread my answer to your question.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- I just hope that policy post and your question now have been satisfactorily answered! This has been a very long process.

Comment: @elemtilas Why do we need an entirely new stack for worldbuilding but for a different world origin? And how is that supposed to solve anything?

Comment: @IchthysKing We don't need a new stack. You want a place to ask questions that aren't a good fit here. We're not obligated to provide that for you.

Comment: @sphennings Why don't they fit? You can't just say it doesn't fit and expect everyone to accept it

Comment: @sphennings And if the rules are against something that we can't even determine, then isn't that more of a problem with the rules than the untestables?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Like I said yesterday: *You can answer your own question better than I can! -- You complained that some questions were becoming lost. Like I said, you have options, and one valid option is for you to propose a new group at Area 51.* You complained about there being no forum for the kinds of questions you're interested in asking. I gave you two options.

Comment: @elemtilas That doesn't help. Would it be OK to ban cat owners from this stack if there were other sites that allowed cat-owners?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- The questions don't fit a) because they're about third party worlds, b) inherently idea fishing, c) opinion based, d) too broad and e) lacking focus. Any one of those reasons is enough to get that kind of question closed. Unfortunately, SE can, and does, expect everyone to accept it. That's how their system works. WB already goes to extreme lengths to bend SE's rules just to exist!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- How doesn't that help? You complained that there was no forum, and I suggested you start your own or join up at Codidact, given the higher content expectation. Seems like two valid options to me! And it sure beats consistently arguing about why your questions get closed here.

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Now we agree on something! I totally agree with you that there are "problems" with SE's rules. But those "problems" only exist because our kind of forum is a terrible fit for the SE model. And that's a completely different topic of discussion, and one for which there is absolutely no solution!

Comment: @elemtilas *"The questions don't fit..."* I could make all the same assertions about questions made by cat owners. Or people who don't have cats. Please explain give at least some rationale for your points

Comment: @IchthysKing -- All the explanations have already been given to you. Numerous times in comments to your questions, in the Policy question you're asking about, in my response to your query and here in comments. If you think there is a specific rationale I have not addressed properly then please point it out so I can try to explain better!

Comment: @elemtilas *"How doesn't that help?..."* Then why shouldn't we ban cat owners? They could go propose a new stack for worldbuilding while owning a cat, or go to somewhere else where they aren't banned for having a cat

Comment: @elemtilas *"All the explanations have already been given to you..."* You have not explained a single way in which third-party questions are inherently close-worthy. All you have done is say that they'd need to be closed if you assume they break the rules. That isn't an argument, at least not one worth listening to

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Why are cat owners relevant? I guess if you want to ban them, make a proposal to ban them!

Comment: @IchthysKing -- I've already explained the issue of third-party worlds being closeworthy *numerous times*. Do please review the linked policy discussion and my response to your question. But to quickly recap: 1) those worlds don't belong to you while the stated mission of the forum is to help *you* with problems & questions within *your own* worldbuilding; 2) wildly speculative questions are a) highly opinion based and b) lack focus. I'm not saying anything new to you. No. 1 is the current policy of WB, and we've already reviewed the remedies. Though I think...

Comment: @IchthysKing -- ... I didn't mention a third possibility and that is to craft a proposal to overturn the third-world party policy. That's a path you could go down. No. 2 is straight up SE rules -- how the whole site works.

Comment: @elemtilas *"I've already explained the issue"* Point 1 doesn't explain why the rules of worldbuilding must be that way, and point 2 is completely irrelevent

Comment: @IchthysKing -- Point 1: I've already explained why! When someone else makes a fictional world, it isn't yours to ask questions about here, and is thus off topic. WB exists for the sole purpose of helping people make ***their own*** fictional worlds. The third party world has already been made! If you want to ask questions about somebody else's work, you can ask on SF&F. This has been explained numerous times. The question of allowing third party world questions here was ...

Comment: @IchthysKing -- ... dealt with definitively [two years ago](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/policy-clarification-asking-about-commercial-or-third-party-worlds). You can read the various arguments yourself and draw your own conclusions as to motives. Point 2 is entirely relative as an adjunct to point one! Even if third party questions were allowed, they'd still be closed for other reasons!

Comment: @elemtilas 1. There are numerous problems with that page that you either haven't fully addressed, addressed in a completely contradictory way, or just ignored entirely. 2. Ideas of any source can be poorly asked about. Unless you think the entire stack needs to be torn down, this is just a double standard

Comment: @IchthysKing -- I did ask you to point out anything specific that I did not address properly.

Comment: @elemtilas Let's go by the points in the question: 1. You've said nothing more than that it's perfectly acceptable for this rule to be wholly unenforceable 2. Your argument here is based on a division of labour between stacks, an idea under which splitting questions by concept origin is utterly ridiculous 3. See previous 4. You haven't addressed this at all

Comment: @IchthysKing -- 1. What rule here *is* enforceable? We assume community members act in good faith. 2. You're certainly welcome to that opinion! I won't try to change to your mind, only point out the fact that this is how the two forums cooperate. 3. Sufficiently addressed, I think. 4. Also sufficiently addressed in the answer. Do you have any specific issues or questions?

Comment: @IchthysKing -- [Here's a good example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/215068/i-would-like-to-know-the-number-of-officers-and-crew-on-the-freedom-lcs) of how to ask a third-party question (in this case, Navyworld). The OP in question has made it clear that the question being asked relates directly to a problem of worldbuilding.  OP is up front about rationale and is not asking about the third party world itself, so doesn't need to be closed re #1 & #2. OP avoids violations of #3 & #4 by stating the purpose for asking about "someone else's world". No "wild speculation"...

Comment: @IchthysKing -- ...or seeking opinions is involved, and the query is focused on a single issue, and is also not about plot or characters. Thus, there is no really valid to close this kind of query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130380/discussion-between-elemtilas-and-ichthys-king).

Answer (score -1):

[Moved to a new question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/proposing-a-tag-for-worldbuilding-questions-that-use-existing-worlds)

Comment: This proposal should probably be a separate question so that it's easier for people to provide feedback and commentary.

Comment: @sphennings Fair enough.