# Is questioning a well known trope on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

The question [Virtual Reality and Physical Trauma](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/105442/virtual-reality-and-physical-trauma) is basically asking if there's any basis to the trope that wounds gained in VR appear in real life.

Is reality checking a known trope on topic?

Comment: Related: [Are questions based on movies okay?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/29)

Comment: The only way such a question is different form most questions here is that someone else came up with the idea and that the OP openly admits and references that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say yes. A trope is just a common bit of worldbuilding, it's no less on-topic than another perhaps more original question. The one place tropes can get a bit off-topic is when they start to delve into specific story-based instances of the trope or where they are asking about a specific story based instance of the trope in a particular other world (that's already built).

I've asked a few questions with a basis in trope (Anything relating to the Starship Exciting Undertaking), but I've always done so tongue-in-cheek and with a firm emphasis on how these tropes could fit in with a world building process.

The VR question is on topic, though I personally would have preferred less of a vague reality check and more of a 'I've tried to make this a thing in my world but got stuck on the details' style of question, though that's just me.

Comment: In truth I never wanted to intigrate this technology into my story.  VR tends to eat up stories (see Shadrow an RPG based on mercenaries raiding corporations for information) and this is made worse as the popular mind  almost demands that VR cause physical wounds. I used an opening ending to check my hypothesis.  I don't think I should apologize for this.  People test hypothese on this forum all the time. Further your form benefited as this post generated some very interesting ideas.

Comment: @JudicalLaser: I don’t think you should apologise either, the question just wasn’t my cup of tea to answer.